# How to disable AdaptiveSizePolicy in JVM?

Tags: jvm, jvm-hotspot

I got a message that if we set min and max of heap size and young generation size to equal separately from [Java Performance], jvm will disable AdaptiveSizePolicy function automatically. 
But this work failed in my test bed of jdk1.6 and 1.7.
Only add option -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy will disable JVM auto scale the young and heap size.

Comment: @Holger, thank you.
I want to verify the description from the book about disable AdaptiveSizePolicy true or false. Is the wrong message in that book, or something else impact my test?

Comment: You can understand my question on this way: I known there are two ways to disable AdaptiveSizePolicy for now, but the first method doesn't work actually in my test, just the second work well. So why the first method failed?

Comment: Maybe it helps when you specify the exact options you’re talking about. Generally, I see no reason why setting min and max for the (total) heap should disable adaptive sizing (of the generations). Regarding the young generation size, as said, it’s helpful to state the exact option, i.e. `-XX:NewSize=…` will only set the *initial size* of the young generation, according to the [tool page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), which implies that adaptive sizing remains active, unless explicitly turned off.

Comment: I also set the max new size with this option : -XX:MaxNewSize, which works when I check by jinfo and jmap -heap

Comment: But there’s still no reason why that should turn off the adaptive sizing and the launcher tool documentation doesn’t specify such behavior.

Comment: It make sense if we set both young space and the entire heap space with fix size, which actually means VM don't need to auto scale the size of them, which equal to disable the AdaptiveSizePolicy.

Comment: Afaik, there is no option to set the young generation to a fixed size, only for an initial size and a maximum size. Or, in other words, disabling adaptive sizing via `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` *is* the way to tell the JVM that the specified initial size is supposed to be a fixed size.

Answer (score 2):

**Set -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy**